# Facebook login with cURL

Tags: facebook, curl, authentication

I tried to login to Facebook with [cURL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL), but then I got this error:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
P3P: CP="Facebook does not have a P3P policy. Learn why here: http://fb.me/p3p"
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: datr=_KpbTjHjH8CWs_EOFbCp4H5r; expires=Wed, 28-Aug-2013 15:06:36 GMT; path=/; domain=.facebook.com; httponly
Set-Cookie: lsd=Mh7wl; path=/; domain=.facebook.com
Set-Cookie: reg_fb_gate=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Flogin.php%3Flogin_attempt%3D1; path=/; domain=.facebook.com
Set-Cookie: reg_fb_ref=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Flogin.php%3Flogin_attempt%3D1; path=/; domain=.facebook.com
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
X-FB-Server: 10.33.22.124
X-Cnection: close
Content-Length: 24058
Date: Mon, 29 Aug 2011 15:06:36 GMT
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It might be because you're not allowed to crawl the website nor access it with a robot. They have an API that can be accessed via cURL.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/) in your web-browser (also in Firefox, Opera and other), you can browse all pages and media files in *Application* tab. To convert it into `curl` command, go to *Network* tab (*refresh* page if necessary or tick *Preserve log*), find the page of your interest (list can be filtered by *Img*), right click on the request, then select [*Copy as cURL*](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/reference#copy). Inspect the content in your clipboard or just paste the command to the terminal.

To convert from `curl` format to `wget`, do the following conversions:

- remove `--compress` parameter,
- change `-H` to `--header` in all places.

Then run the command.

Doing that, please consider [Facebook's Automated Data Collection Terms](https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php).

If you're interested in a backup of all your data, check: [Accessing & Downloading Your Information](https://www.facebook.com/help/1701730696756992).

Related:

- [How to download files from Facebook group?](https://superuser.com/q/1422541/87805)
- [How to download Facebook page?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17591273/55075)
- [wget for fetching Facebook profile/friend pages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6821696/55075)
- [How do I use wget/curl to download from a site I am logged into?](https://askubuntu.com/q/161778/78223)
- [How to download this webpage with Wget?](https://superuser.com/q/214846/87805)
- [Using wget to download images in facebook conversations](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/137772/21471)