# How to download Facebook page?

Tags: php, curl

I want to download a Facebook web page using PHP. I've tried file_get_contents along with stream_context_create. I've also tried Curl. But Facebook is returing only this message:

> Update Your Browser You’re using a web browser that isn’t supported by
>   Facebook. To get a better experience, go to one of these sites and get
>   the latest version of your preferred browser:

Am I missing anything?

Here is the Curl code:

```
       $url="https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.189662541197403.1073741845.188398434657147&type=1&l=a8755a774e";
        $custom_headers = array();
        $custom_headers[] = "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
        $custom_headers[] = "Pragma: no-cache";
        $custom_headers[] = "Cache-Control: no-cache";
        $custom_headers[] = "Accept-Language: en-us;q=0.7,en;q=0.3";
        $custom_headers[] = "Accept-Charset: utf-8,windows-1251;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";

        $ch = curl_init();
        $useragent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:9.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0.1";
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent); // set user agent
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $custom_headers);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,20);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40); //timeout in seconds

        $txResult = curl_exec($ch);

        $statuscode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

        print "$txResult";
```

Comment: Which part of the web page?

Comment: Facebook is mainly a dynamic site driven by Javascript and AJAX. You are going to find it very hard to do this using screen-scraping.

Comment: `Firefox/9.0.1` sounds a bit old.  The latest version is 22.0 as I write this.  Perhaps that's what Facebook doesn't like...

Comment: @jdero this one: https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.189662541197403.1073741845.188398434657147&type=1&l=a8755a774e

Comment: @legoscia Filefox/9.0.1 is the one I'm using and it is able to show me the page.

Comment: @AgA you should update your browser!

Comment: Hmm, since those are public pictures, you might actually not need an access token. Hmm. I'd still go with the API. It's so easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the API instead?

The data for the URL you mentioned can also be retrieved from this one:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/?id=189662541197403
```

Also, that reduces your entire code to this line :

```
json_decode(file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/?id=189662541197403'));
```

Comment: Yes it is working(i get the data I want) .. but wouldn't it be better if I could get the whole page in htm?

Comment: @AgA You couldn't: Facebook uses Javascript to generate their pages.

Answer (score 2):

facebook Api have some restication about fb data

if you want scrap Facebook page you need  wait until all of the Javascript is loaded before curling the page

You need to use a headless browser engine to do this. cURL and wget are HTTP libraries;
 they speak HTTP and download documents as String. They don't have a concept of a DOM or a JavaScript engine that would help them understand that a page is doing AJAX OR JS  . So to download the HTML, you need something that acts more like a browser, by parsing a DOM and executing JS. I recommend http://simile.mit.edu/wiki/Crowbar, which uses a Mozilla engine.
once the js run you easily scrap content you want

I hope this is help-full for you  :)